# Arduino maximum interrupt frequency

Tags: arduino, counter, interrupt

I'm working on an Arduino m0 pro. I would like to know what is the maximum frequency for an interrupts. I would like to develop a system that, thanks to the interrupt overflow routine, outputs different values at each interrupt. Till now I followed this topic:
http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=425385.0;nowap

I want to do the same thing but with frequency of 25kHz, I tried to do it but in output I obtain just a constant signal. Is it possible to reach the frequency of 25kHz with an Arduino M0 pro? 
In order to obtain an output every 39.06 microseconds (25kHz) what formula should I use?

This is my code:

```
int i = 0;
int sintable[256] PROGMEM={512,524,537,549,562,574,587,599,611,624,636,648,660,672,684,696,707,719,30,741,753,764,774,785,796,806,816,826,836,846,855,864,873,882,890,899,907,915,922,930,937,944,950,957,963,968,974,979,984,989,993,997,1001,1004,1008,1011,1013,1015,1017,1019,1021,1022,1022,1023,1023,1023,1022,1022,1021,1019,1017,1015,1013,1011,1008,1004,1001,997,993,989,984,979,974,968,963,957,950,944,937,930,922,915,907,899,890,882,873,864,855,846,836,826,816,806,796,785,774,764,753,741,730,719,707,696,684,672,660,648,636,624,611,599,587,574,562,549,537,524,512,499,486,474,461,449,436,424,412,399,387,375,363,351,339,327,316,304,293,282,270,259,249,238,227,217,207,197,187,177,168,159,150,141,133,124,116,108,101,93,86,79,73,66,60,55,49,44,39,34,30,26,22,19,15,12,10,8,6,4,2,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,4,6,8,10,12,15,19,22,26,30,34,39,44,49,55,60,66,73,79,86,93,101,108,116,124,133,141,150,159,168,177,187,197,207,217,227,238,249,259,270,282,293,304,316,327,339,351,363,375,387,399,412,424,436,449,461,474,486,499};

void setup() {
    analogWriteResolution(10);
    // Set up the generic clock (GCLK4) used to clock timers
    REG_GCLK_GENDIV = GCLK_GENDIV_DIV(1) |          // Divide the 48MHz clock source by divisor 1: 48MHz/1=48MHz
                      GCLK_GENDIV_ID(4);            // Select Generic Clock (GCLK) 4
    while (GCLK->STATUS.bit.SYNCBUSY);              // Wait for synchronization

    REG_GCLK_GENCTRL = GCLK_GENCTRL_IDC |           // Set the duty cycle to 50/50 HIGH/LOW
                       GCLK_GENCTRL_GENEN |         // Enable GCLK4
                       GCLK_GENCTRL_SRC_DFLL48M |   // Set the 48MHz clock source
    GCLK_GENCTRL_ID(4);          // Select GCLK4
    while (GCLK->STATUS.bit.SYNCBUSY);              // Wait for synchronization

  // Feed GCLK4 to TC4 and TC5
        REG_GCLK_CLKCTRL = GCLK_CLKCTRL_CLKEN |         // Enable GCLK4 to TC4 and TC5
                           GCLK_CLKCTRL_GEN_GCLK4 |     // Select GCLK4
                           GCLK_CLKCTRL_ID_TC4_TC5;     // Feed the GCLK4 to TC4 and TC5
    while (GCLK->STATUS.bit.SYNCBUSY);              // Wait for synchronization

    REG_TC4_COUNT16_CC0 = 0xEA;                    // Set the TC4 CC0 register as the TOP value in match frequency mode
    while (TC4->COUNT16.STATUS.bit.SYNCBUSY);       // Wait for synchronization

    NVIC_SetPriority(TC4_IRQn, 0);                  // Set the Nested Vector Interrupt Controller (NVIC) priority for TC4 to 0 (highest)
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TC4_IRQn);                       // Connect TC4 to Nested Vector Interrupt Controller (NVIC)

    REG_TC4_INTFLAG |= TC_INTFLAG_OVF;              // Clear the interrupt flags
    REG_TC4_INTENSET = TC_INTENSET_OVF;             // Enable TC4 interrupts

    REG_TC4_CTRLA |= TC_CTRLA_PRESCALER_DIV8 |      // Set prescaler to 1024, 48MHz/1024 = 46.875kHz
                     TC_CTRLA_WAVEGEN_MFRQ |        // Put the timer TC4 into match frequency (MFRQ) mode 
                     TC_CTRLA_ENABLE;               // Enable TC4
    while (TC4->COUNT16.STATUS.bit.SYNCBUSY);       // Wait for synchronization
}

void loop() {}

void TC4_Handler()                                // Interrupt Service 
Routine (ISR) for timer TC4
{     
  // Check for overflow (OVF) interrupt
  if (TC4->COUNT16.INTFLAG.bit.OVF && TC4->COUNT16.INTENSET.bit.OVF){ 
    analogWrite(A0,sintable[i]);
    i++;
    if(i==256)
      i=0;
    REG_TC4_INTFLAG = TC_INTFLAG_OVF;         // Clear the OVF interrupt flag 
  }
}
```

Comment: provide your code. "I tried to do it" is not something you can expect any help for

Comment: Post modified with the code.

Comment: how fast can you send stuff in a loop... that might be a pretty good indication of how fast you could possibly go... 25KB/s should be doable over serial... but you aren't that far away from 56KB/s which is as fast as most serial applications ever got (rs-232 should theoretically be able to go faster than it does in practice... to get up to signal level it usually has some charge pump caps that have to get charged for every bit.)

Comment: @GradyPlayer sorry but I haven't got your point. Could you be more clear?

Comment: just send data in a while loop and see how fast you can send it, abstract away the signal handler stuff (you shouldn't generally do io in a signal handler anyway)

Comment: How can I measure how fast I can send the data?

Comment: Look for the formula in the datasheet.  Measure using a free IO pin and an oscilloscope. If you don't have a scope, bring voltage high when entering the ISR, liow when exiting, add a resistor and a cap to the pin and measure the voltage.